# How to compile a Hello World assembly on Windows?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, assembly, masm

Having such a simple `assembly` `Win 32` program:

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap :none

EXTERN printf :PROC ; declare printf

.data
    HelloWorld db "Hello Wolrd!:-)", 0

.code
start:
  sub esp, 4
  push offset HelloWorld
  call printf
  add esp, 4
  ret
end start
```

I can successfully compile it by just:

```
ml.exe /c HelloWorld.asm
```

BUT have a problem linking it. When I use:

```
link HelloWorld.obj libcmt.lib
```

I'm getting an error:

```
unresolved external symbol _main called in _mainCRTStartup
```

What have I change/correct to to successfully link the program to run it?

P.S.

Please don't tell me to use just `nasm`. I'd like to use `ml` & `link` from my MSVC.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `ml.exe /c /coff HelloWorld.asm`, `link /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE HelloWorld.obj libcmt.lib` ?

Comment: @Michael I'v tried Your's proposal but still having the same linker error.:-(..

Comment: Nobody's going to tell you to use NASM; it couldn't assemble this file that uses MASM syntax / directives.  And NASM is just an assembler, doesn't come with a linker anyway.

Answer (score 2):

With some minor tweaks this now builds correctly.

```
.386    
.model flat, c
option casemap :none

includelib libcmt.lib
includelib legacy_stdio_definitions.lib

EXTERN printf :PROC ; declare printf

.data
    HelloWorld db "Hello World!:-)", 0

.code
main PROC
  push offset HelloWorld
  call printf
  add esp, 4
  ret
main ENDP
END
```

The main edits are

- **.model flat, c** sets the calling conventions for procedures to C.
  If you decide to keep **.model flat, stdcall** it'll require these changes.

Replace

```
EXTERN printf :PROC

main PROC
```

with

```
printf PROTO NEAR C,:DWORD

main PROC NEAR C
```

- Included **libcmt.lib** and **legacy_stdio_definitions.lib** which statically links the native C-Runtime startup into your code.
- Changed entry point from **start** to **main**. There's an entry point (_mainCRTStartup) within the C-Runtime library (CRT) libcmt.lib, which does some initialization tasks, and then hands off control to the entry point for your application **main**. You can change the default entry point, but usually you want the convenience of the initialization the CRT entry point does for you automatically.
- Removed the first **sub esp,4** so the remaining one push is balanced by the add esp,4, so ESP is pointing at the return address when ret runs.

To build, open a Windows command prompt and run:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars32.bat"
```

to set the MSVC Environment initialized for: 'x86'

Next, run these MASM commands

```
ml.exe /c /coff HelloWorld.asm

link.exe /SUBSYSTEM:console HelloWorld.obj
```

The program displays

Hello World!:-)

Comment: You should mention the things you changed, like `main` instead of `start`, and removing the first `sub esp,4` so the remaining one push is balanced by the `add esp,4`, so ESP is pointing at the return address when `ret` runs.

Comment: @vengy Thx friend it finally works!:-) BUT I'm getting a linker warning that .CRT section was merged with the .data section with different attributes... What does it mean an how to correct this?

Comment: A quick fix is to add the /MERGE linker option in x86 to merge the .CRT section (read only) with the .rdata (read only) sections: link.exe /SUBSYSTEM:console /MERGE:.CRT=.rdata  HelloWorld.obj

Answer (score 0):

Your error message says that it can't find the exported symbol (i.e. function) "_main". I expect renaming your start function to _main would get it to compile.

Comment: I've renamed `start` to `_main` and also tried even `_mainCRTStartup` but STILL no luck...

Comment: @darek_911: maybe try calling it `main`; I think I've read that MASM may optionally decorate names for you with a leading `_`, depending on some directives or options.  But yeah, certainly `start` (and the lack of a _main symbol) is a problem, probably *the* problem.